# CSS - Get image to show text overlayed on top of the image on hover?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a few list items. Each one has an image followed by some text.

```css
ul {
    width:300px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></a>
        <a href="#">Cool image</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></a>
        <a href="#">Cool image</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></a>
        <a href="#">Cool image</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm having trouble seeing how/if I can do this with pure css? I'd like the image to have the text on top of it on hover (kinda like how imgur.com does it.) On imgur.com if you hover over a thumbnail, at the bottom it tells you how many upvotes something has. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly - you simply need to add position text absolutely inside relatively positioned `LI` item. And don't forget to add your `.thumbnail` class to `LI`s.
You may also play around a bit with text positioning using `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` CSS properties.

**Note:** to make text visible only on hover - simply hide text by default with `display:none` and show it on `:hover` event.
**Note2:** also animation could be added via `transitions` and opacity.

```css
ul {
    width:300px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.thumbnail {
    position:relative;
}

.thumbnail .text {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.thumbnail:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="thumbnail">
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></a>
        <a href="#" class="text">Cool image</a>
    </li>
    <li class="thumbnail">
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></a>
        <a href="#" class="text">Cool image</a>
    </li>
    <li class="thumbnail">
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></a>
        <a href="#" class="text">Cool image</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's perfect... but how would I go about only showing "Cool Image" on hover?

Comment: Also, how would I go about have the text show at the bottom left instead of the top left? I tried just replacing top 0 with bottom 0 , but then all of my links end up matching up to the wrong image.

Comment: @EGHDK, just give a bit more space to links with `bottom: 5px;` (see updated answer). If it doesn't resolve the issue - let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class='container'>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
            <p>Cool image</p>
        </div>
   </li>
    ...
</ul>

.container {
    position:relative;
}

.container p {
    position:absolute;
    width: ;
    height: ;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}


.container:hover .container p {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these Steps:

1. Make the `li` `position:relative`
2. Make the image and text `position: absolute` and `top: 0;left: 0`
3. Give `opacity: 0` to text
4. make `opacity: 1` on hover

   `[img containing a]:hover ~ [text element] {
       opacity: 1;
   }`

Here is a fiddle of what I suggested: http://jsfiddle.net/zdz8x6wq/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

Note that there is just one link per <li>, and that the overlay is inside it.

```css
ul {
    width:300px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    position:relative;
}
.thumbnailContainer:link .overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    opacity:0.7;
    display:none;
    width:350px;
    height:150px;
}
.thumbnailContainer:hover .overlay {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="thumbnailContainer" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <div class="overlay">Cool image</div></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="thumbnailContainer" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <div class="overlay">Cool image</div></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="thumbnailContainer" href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <div class="overlay">Cool image</div></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
```